# Extending VueJs bundled Typescript definitions for VueRx

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'd like to use [VueRx](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-rx) in a Typescript project.

VueRx extends the Vue prototype with several methods: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-rx#other-api-methods. Since VueRx does not ship with TS declarations, I would like to roll my own. Unfortunately I'm unable to come up with a way to extend the Vue declarations bundled with VueJs due to the way the declaration is written (classes rather than interfaces). Any suggestions?